# Confused by this proof in Jech's set theory

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, set-theory, descriptive-set-theory, borel-sets

In Jech's Set Theory, Chapter 11, the universal set $U$ is defined as: For each $\alpha \geq 1$, there exists a set $U \subset \mathcal{N}^2$ such that $U$ is $\Sigma_{\alpha}^0$ (in $\mathcal{N}^2$) and that for every $\Sigma_{\alpha}^0$ set $A$ in $\mathcal{N}$, there exists some $a \in \mathcal{N}$ such that $A = \{x:(x,a) \in U\}$. Here, $\mathcal{N}$ refers to the set $\omega^{\omega}$ (i.e. the Baire space), and $\Sigma_{\alpha}^0$, $\Pi_{\alpha}^0$ for some ordinal $\alpha$ are collections of sets that form the Borel heirarchy.

The proof that $U$ exists is done by induction on $\alpha$. Namely, let $U$ be a universal $\Sigma_{\alpha}^0$ set, we can construct a universal set $V$ that is $\Sigma_{\alpha+1}^0$, and the idea is:

$$
(x,y) \in V \text{ if and only if for some $n$}, (x,y_{(n)}) \not \in U
$$

Where $y_{(n)}$ is $y_{(n)}(k)=y(\Gamma(n,k))$ and $\Gamma : N \times N \rightarrow N$ is some one-to-one and onto pairing function. It follows that if $(x,y_{(n)}) \not \in U$, then $(x,y_{(n)})$ belongs to a $\Pi_{\alpha}^0$ set.

Now, in the next paragraph of the proof, we have that if $A$ is some $\Sigma_{\alpha+1}^0$ set in $\mathcal{N}$, then $A=\bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty}A_n$, where each $A_n$ is $\Pi_{\alpha}^0$ (i.e. which is the definition of $\Sigma_{\alpha+1}^0$). For each $n$, let $a_n$ be such that $\mathcal{N} - A_n = \{x : (x,a_n) \in U \}$, and let $a$ be such that $a_{(n)} = a_n$ for all $n$. Then $A = \{ x: (x,a) \in V \}$.

I am not sure how $A = \{ x: (x,a) \in V \}$ satisfies the definition of $V$ that $(x,y) \in V \text{ if and only if for some $n$}, (x,y_{(n)}) \not \in U$, because if $a_{(n)} = a_n$ for all $n$ and $a_n$ is such that $(x,a_n) \in U$ (as per previous paragraph), then doesn't that imply that $(x,a_{(n)}) = (x,a_n) \in U$ ?

(edit$^1$: unless of course, I take into account the implicit fact that $\Sigma_{\alpha}^0 \subset \Sigma_{\alpha+1}^0$ and $\Pi_{\alpha}^0 \subset \Sigma_{\alpha+1}^0$ for all ordinals $\alpha$ ... but this fact wasn't mentioned at all in the proof so I may be missing something here...)

(edit$^2$: or is it because each $x \subset \mathcal{N} \times \mathcal{N}$ is both open and closed ?)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49613/sigma-alpha10x-universal-set-based-on-the-baire-space may be related.

Comment: $(x,a_n)\in U$ iff $x\not\in A_n$, so that $(x,a_n)\not\in U$ iff $x\in A_n$, that is $(x,a_n)\not\in U$ for some $n$ iff $x\in A$, as desired.

Comment: Let me try to give some intuition for what is going on here. $U$ is coding $\Sigma^0_\alpha$ subsets of $\mathcal N$ by elements of $\mathcal N$, where we think about $a\in\mathcal N$ as the code for $\{x\in\mathcal N\mid (x,a)\in U\}$. Now if $U$ is $\Sigma^0_\alpha$-universal, then $\mathcal N^2\setminus U$ is $\Pi^0_\alpha$-universal (easy to check). Moreover we can code a sequence of elements of $\mathcal N$ by a single element of $\mathcal N$, by fixing a homeomorphism $\mathcal N\to\mathcal N^\omega$...

Comment: Now to code a $\Sigma^0_{\alpha+1}$ set $A$ we only need to code a sequence of $\Pi^0_\alpha$ sets $A_n$ with $A=\bigcup A_n$. But by the above each of the $A_n$'s is coded by an element $a_n\in\mathcal N$ as $\{x\in\mathcal N\mid (x,a_n)\not\in U\}$, and we can code the whole sequence $(a_n)$ into a single element of $\mathcal N$. The rest is checking a few annoying indices, but this is the idea behind this argument

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti ok thank you very much for taking time to comment ... what I dont understand is how $a_n$ is used in this line: $\mathcal{N} - A_n = \{ x | (x,a_n) \in U\}$ ... if the code $a_n$ is used in this way: $A_n = \{x| (x,a_n) \not \in U\}$ then it would make more sense ... what am I missing ?

Comment: I don't think you're missing anything. Saying that $\mathcal N-A_n=\{x\in\mathcal N\mid (x,a_n)\in U\}$ and saying that $A_n=\{x\in\mathcal N\mid (x,a_n)\not\in U\}$ are equivalent. I guess Jech chose the first option because he's assuming that $U$ is $\Sigma^0_\alpha$-universal, and $\mathcal N-A_n$ is $\Sigma^0_\alpha$ so by assumption we know that we can write the first option

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti ok ... so I guess my confusion comes from assuming that the $a_n$ in $\mathcal{N}-A_n=\{x|(x,a_n) \in U\}$ is exactly the same $a_n$ used in $A_n=\{x|(x,a_n) \not \in U\}$ ... because if they're the same, then we get $(x,a_n) \in U$ and $(x,a_n) \not \in U$, which is a contradiction, so these $a_n$'s should actually be treated as distinct (i.e. one is used for membership in $\Sigma_\alpha^0$ and the other one for membership in $\Pi_\alpha^0$)... am I correct here ? Thank you for your help !

Comment: No, they are the same $a_n$! There is no contradiction, you're forgetting that the $x$'s are subject to some conditions. More specifically we get $(x,a_n)\in U$ iff $x\not\in A_n$, while we get $(x,a_n)\not\in U$ iff $x\in A_n$, there is no contradiction because those two cases are disjoint sets of $x$'s. It might be clearer if you draw a picture of $U\subseteq\mathcal N^2$ and draw $A_n$ in $\mathcal N\times\{a_n\}$

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti oh ok ! i didn't  understand that the set of $x$'s in these two cases are distinct ... that fixes everything for me thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turning some comments into an answer.

Since $U\subseteq\mathcal N^2$ is $\mathbf{\Sigma}^0_\alpha$-universal and $A_n\subseteq\mathcal N$ is $\mathbf{\Pi}^0_\alpha$, so that $\mathcal N-A_n$ is $\mathbf{\Sigma}^0_\alpha$, we must have $$\mathcal N-A_n=\{x\in\mathcal N\mid (x,a_n)\in U\},$$ for some $a_n\in\mathcal N$. But this is equivalent to saying that $$A_n=\{x\in\mathcal N\mid (x,a_n)\not\in U\},$$ for the same $a_n\in\mathcal N$ as above.

That being said let me try to explain the intuition behind this argument. The fact that $U\subseteq\mathcal N^2$ is $\mathbf{\Sigma}^0_\alpha$-universal means that $U$ is coding $\mathbf{\Sigma}^0_\alpha$ subsets of $\mathcal N$ by elements of $\mathcal N$, by thinking about $a\in\mathcal N$ as the code for the set $\{x\in\mathcal N\mid (x,a)\in U\}$. Now note that if we can find a $\mathbf{\Sigma}^0_\alpha$-universal set $U\subseteq\mathcal N^2$, then we can also find a $\mathbf{\Pi}^0_\alpha$-universal set $U'\subseteq\mathcal N^2$, since it is enough to take $U'=\mathcal N^2\setminus U$. The point now is that to find a $\mathbf{\Sigma}^0_{\alpha+1}$-universal set, one should note that every $\mathbf{\Sigma}^0_{\alpha+1}$ set $A$ is determined by a countable sequence of $\mathbf{\Pi}^0_\alpha$ sets $A_n$ with $A=\bigcup_n A_n$, and we already know how to code the sequence $(A_n)$ with an element of $\mathcal N^\omega$, since we know how to code each $A_n$ with an element of $\mathcal N$. But $\mathcal N$ is homeomorphic to $\mathcal N^\omega$ so we are done.